# C# Lock contention on structs?

Tags: c#, performance, struct, locking

I'm playing with structs in C# which look like this:

```
public struct UnitData
{
    public int ID { get; init; }
    public Vector2 XY { get; set; }
}
```

and while profiling I seem to get a significant amount of time spent in lock contention when accessing the `XY` field (alongside similar locks for any access to the data).

[image: profile of structs]

If I change the implementation to go from a `struct` to a `class` this overhead goes away. I don't have any locks in the code that uses this and while the program is multi-threaded the code that uses this data in on a single background thread.

Looking at the IL code there isn't any mention of `Monitor.Enter` or `Monitor.Exit` in the code using this nor the property itself.

**Where does the lock come from** if it's not in my code and **how I remove the overhead while still using structs?**

Example usage of `XY`:

```
public IEnumerable<int> MoveNext(Vector2 location, float radius)
{
    foreach (UnitData item in m_units.Items)
    {
        if (Vector2.Distance(location, item.XY) <= radius)
        {
            yield return item.ID;
        }
    }
}
```

In the above example `m_units.Items` is a `T[]` property pointing to `T[]? m_data;` with the generic type `UnitData`, this property caches the results into the `m_data` array after the first access to avoid recalculation.

Comment: Where do you use the `XY`-property?

Comment: @TimSchmelter I added the code that is from the `MoveNext` method in the profiler screenshot

Comment: What profiler are you using to generate those results?

Comment: @dbc Jetbrains DotTrace 2023.1 (locks happen in both a debug and release build)

Comment: I wonder whether DotTrace is mis-reporting time spent in copying structs around as lock contention?

Comment: @dbc It's possible.... Trying to get a minimal repo case for this behaviour at the moment to make it easier for others to look at this.

Comment: @dbc I don't think that's the case, moving an array of 100,000,000 `UnitData` around the DotTrace shows the time spent was in "Native Code" with "ntoskrnl.exe" being the thing taking the execution time. I think this is the core kernel for modern windows versions, probably executing the memory copy/move.

Comment: I was able to get a bit of speedup using `Vector2.DistanceSquared`, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/ePjAfM.

Comment: But I have no idea why dotTrace might be reporting time spent in `[lock contention]` unless it has something to do with time spent in jitting or optimization, since all the relevant [`Vector2` methods](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Numerics/Vector2.cs#L276) are marked with `[Intrinsic]` and `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]`.

Comment: @dbc It wouldn't even necessarily be mis-reported; maybe the CLR guarantees the copy will be atomic in a case like that? I wonder if making the field (or entire struct) read only would change anything. I'm also wondering about the profiling procedure - preheating and all that.

Comment: @Luaan - Your point about preheating is well take.  Eric Lipper's articles on .NET benchmarking are a good read: https://ericlippert.com/2013/05/14/benchmarking-mistakes-part-one/, https://ericlippert.com/2013/05/21/benchmarking-mistakes-part-two/, https://ericlippert.com/2013/07/09/benchmarking-mistakes-part-three/ and https://ericlippert.com/2013/08/19/benchmarking-mistakes-part-four/